# Installation from USB stick on UEFI-based system

Tags: installation, 64-bit, uefi

How can I install Ubuntu from USB stick on a UEFI-based x86-64 system? 
Documentation for this topic doesn't look very friendly.

Comment: see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallUbuntu11.10OnLenovoEFI/GPT/WLAN/Power/BIOS)

Comment: Since nothing much has changed in the construction of `.iso` images from 11.10 to 12.04, solutions to [How to boot Ubuntu from EFI/UEFI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91484/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-efi-uefi) (which [GaRyu found](http://askubuntu.com/a/163326/22949)) should apply here, and further work on this topic can happen there. Therefore, we may close this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Is it possible to disable secure boot in your system?

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the threads at ubuntuforum.org?

For example: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2015019

There is also answers here on Ask Ubuntu for previous versions of Ubuntu: [How to boot Ubuntu from EFI/UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91484/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-efi-uefi)

Not that I know anything about this topic, I just did a google search for you.