# How Do I install Ubuntu using UEFI

Tags: 12.04, installation, uefi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to boot Ubuntu from EFI/UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91484/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-efi-uefi)

Sorry, I know there have been similar questions, but the answers to them did not help me.
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my new Sony Vaio S15 (64 Bit), which uses UEFI, but so far I haven't gotten it to work. Windows 7 has to use UEFI. With Legacy I get an error message: operating system not found, but Ubuntu starts fine from both CD and USB drive. But I don't want to shift back and forth every time I have to use Windows.

Can anybody please tell me what I can do to install Ubuntu using UEFI?

(I don't want to use the Windows installer as it seems I cannot set the size of the partitions myself...)

Comment: Did you check [How to boot Ubuntu from EFI/UEFI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91484/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-efi-uefi?rq=1)? This probably includes the answer to your question.

Comment: Agreed is a duplicate but sarcasm was probably unecessary

Comment: @Jacob Izzy's post doesn't register on my sarcastic meter, and asking whether a question is a duplicate is common and not especially controversial on Ask Ubuntu. It's all rote archiving work. In general, assume good intentions until someone proves themself malicious, the internet works better that way. :)

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards +1 :)

Comment: Yes I appreciate this but it did just appear a little sarcastic as putting "This probably includes the answer to your question." after posting an exact duplicate appears a little patronising. But I do appreciate that I was a little tired that day and so was just being a bit snarky, apologies if I come off as rude.