# Ubuntu 12.04 not booting after installation alongside Windows 7 in UEFI mode

Tags: 12.04, grub2, 64-bit, windows-7

I've tried to fix GRUB using Boot Repair. It didn't work, but it produced an info summary*.

When the computer starts Windows 7 is launched without any GRUB message.

---

*<sub>editor's note: the link to which has died</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I see you have chosen to install `grub`. But your laptop setup indicates it boot through efi.

So you need to install `grub-efi` not `grub`.

Re run the `boot-repair` program and choose recommended repair.

More information is available in [How to boot Ubuntu from EFI/UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91484/35775).

Let us know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command.

```
sudo update-grub
```

(make sure it shows an entry for Windows 7)

```
sudo reboot
```