# I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS on an external drive from a CD but it will not boot. iMac 2011, OSX 10.7.4

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, mac, external-hdd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to boot Ubuntu from EFI/UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91484/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-efi-uefi)

I have followed all installation instructions and partitioned the drive as follows:

475 GB for Ubuntu and its files
25 GB of swap space
5 MB of reserved BIOS boot space

I attempted placing the bootloader in the BIOS boot space, in the Ubuntu partition, and on the drive itself - none worked.  When I tried to boot Ubuntu, it said that the drive was not bootable and asked for a boot disk.  When I put one in, it gave the default screen asking if I wanted to try Ubuntu or install.

Did I do anything wrong?  Any help is much appreciated; I'm getting really tired of OSX and love the look and feel of Ubuntu...

**-edit-**  I have installed and am using rEFInd and I can use Super Grub 2 from a disk, but neither recognizes Ubuntu as a bootable OS.  I tried following the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ubuntupreciseon2011imac
and am stuck where it says

```
"select somethind like 'detect even if the MBR is overwritten', select the only entry which will appear and boot ubuntu normaly, but just due to super grub disk 2."
```

because Grub reports that there is nothing there.

(I will boot with Grub loaded in the drive, and select it at the screen where you can boot OSX, Windows (mislabeled, it's actually the Ubuntu installation on my second drive) and my Grub CD.  I will then select the option to find previous Grub installations as prompted by the website, and that's where I will get the error.  Grub also fails to find Ubuntu with it's list all OSes option.)

Comment: you installed your ubuntu on external harddrive or imac harddrive it self ?

Comment: Ubuntu is installed in the partitions listed on the external hard drive