# Hardware compatibility on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, hardware, compatibility

I'm looking to update my pc with new hardware, currently I'm running Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with dual boot.

I have this hardware in mind:

- Motherboard: ASRock Z77 Extreme4
- CPU: Intel Core i5 2500K 3.3Ghz Box Socket 1155
- RAM: G.Skill RipjawsZ DDR3 2400 PC3-19200 16GB 4X4GB CL10

I have read that there are some problems with ivy/sandy bridges and UEFI motherboards, are they fixed in 12.04?

Will it work?

Any thoughts?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the UEFI part see this question and the answer for more information [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

For the hardware, The **Intel Z77 Chipset** has no problems that I am aware of. The ASRock, since it is using the Z77 Chipset, should work out of the box. For the issue regarding UEFI, you can either disable UEFI from the BIOS options or do what the link I provided offers in regards to installing Ubuntu with a system that has UEFI enabled. More info about this in [How to boot Ubuntu from EFI/UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91484/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-efi-uefi)

For the video card in the CPU it should also work out of the box (No problems with Ivy or Sandy technology).

Of course, you would need to use the latest update of 12.04 which is 12.04.2 and download the 64 bit version (32 Bit will not work). More info about this in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop