# Install Ubuntu on ASUS K55N(UEFI) laptop

Tags: installation, boot, 64-bit, uefi

I recently bought an Asus K55N-DB81 laptop, which uses UEFI. When I boot in UEFI mode onto the installation disk and select "Install Ubuntu", the computer outputs onto the screen "binary whitelisted". Also, when I boot using the "legacy" BIOS, it displays nothing and the disk turns off.

I have posted a thread at ubuntuforums [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2169256)

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to boot Ubuntu from EFI/UEFI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91484/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-efi-uefi)

Comment: No, that computer could install Ubuntu. Mine can't even boot the installation media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems with my Asus K55N not wanting to boot ubuntu. I tried changing all sorts of settings in the BIOS to no avail and couldn't find anything in the ubuntu forums to help. Finally I found this [linux mint thread](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=140874) which solved my problem.

Just follow the steps outlined towards the bottom of the thread and that should fix it. I only had to do the first three steps and that was enough to get it to boot.

Comment: P.S. I think I just posted essentially the same response to your question in ubuntu forums :)

Comment: Ok, I ended up installing Arch Linux(which can use the UEFI on the K55N :D), but thank you for the answer!