# Installation on an UEFI system

Tags: boot, system-installation, 13.04, uefi

I've been using Ubuntu for years. Now I've bought a new notebook and want to install Ubuntu again but I can't. My notebook is a Lenovo S300 ieadpad with preinstalled Windows 8. I want Ubuntu to be my only OS.

Here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI I read some instructions on how install Ubuntu on a UEFI system. So I downloaded ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso and created a live USB. On the USB, there is now a Virtualbox, is that right?

Then I tried to follow the steps described on the named webpage. The problem is, I can find neither Quickboost nor the Intel Smart Response Technology in my BIOS.

I tried to simply boot from USB but this didn't work. In this case, the Lenovo Logo appears and nothing happens.

Comment: I'd recommend you to check out this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/95701/48451. When I bought my laptop it came with Windows 8 and UEFI and after reading the Luis Alvarado's answer I could easily install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you diable UEFI booting. In your BIOS it should look like this:

[image]

Change ENABLED to DISABLED and boot the USB. Usually you use the arrow keys to go up and down and once UEFI is highlighted, hit enter.

If you do NOT have that option, see if there is an update available for your BIOS.

In practice, all I could find is a thread on the forums where the netbook was "DOA" due to a "bug in the BIOS"

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2093845

You may have to contact Lenovo directly. They have a reputation of supporting Linux.

As a side note, I have noticed it is becoming customary to disable bios options in newer computers. In that event, absent a BIOS update or support from Lenovo, you would have to write your own BIOS.

http://www.bios-mods.com/

Obviously support is "use at your own risk" and you can render your machine completely recoverable.

Comment: I tried to look at your links, but they are too large - 1,519.12 KB (1,555,578 bytes). You do not normally have Intel SRT unless you have the separate SSD which is then an Ultrabook or higher end system. You should have in Windows or UEFI fastboot setting which you need to turn off. Then you should be able to boot in UEFI or BIOS.

Comment: Hi oldfred, good to see you.

Comment: Ich habe den Fastboot im Windows 8 ausgeschaltet, aber es hilft nicht. Der Computer will einfach nicht vom USB booten. Ich habe auch an den Lenovo Support geschrieben, bin gerade aber etwas verzweifelt. Wubi funktioniert auch nicht.

Comment: Sorry, in English:
I turned off the fastboot in windows 8 but the computer still does not boot from the USB. Any other ideas?