# Ubunto Won't Boot

Tags: boot

I tried to do the partitions also i tried to just click on "Erase and install", everytime is not booting.
It shows a black screen with a line on left.
I also tried to reinstall bootloader.I m running just Ubuntu ,NO Windows, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I selected" then where do you select?
From this little information, I assume you have a newer computer using EFI Boot?
You need to go into BIOS setting and select the right boot target.
Boot mode EFI 
Target /boot/EFI/ubunutu/grubx64.efi
More info here:
[How to boot Ubuntu from EFI/UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91484/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-efi-uefi)

This said, i assume that your system is okay and only the bootloader got lost.
Had this already a few times. It is scary, but one it is fixed everything is like before.
I hope you did not erase partitions, as this wipes all data in a partition forever.

Maybe a bit more information would surely help.
what is your system configuration?
Did it work before?
What is your configuration?
aso.

Do you see a Grub menu?